# Pine Script Indicator - Sunday Open Horizontal Line

Tags: line, pine-script, indicator

I'm stuck and need some help please... I'm trying to create a indicator which draws a horizontal line from the Sunday Daily Open candle for the upcoming week. I found the code below as an example, which works for simple line, but the line is too short; it only continues for a day - I would want it to plot through to the following Sunday open (if this isn't possible it's also fine to just extend the line, and delete all previous lines.. or I was thinking a continuous step line could be best?)

The chart below shows how I want it to look, whether step line or individual lines for each week. But I wouldn't want them all to extend to the end of the chart, would be too messy.

[image]

```
study(title="Sunday Open", shorttitle="Sunday Open", overlay=true)
openPrice = security(tickerid, 'D', open)
isSunday() => dayofweek(time('D')) == sunday ? 1 : 0
plot(isSunday() and openPrice ? openPrice:  na, title="Sunday Open",   style=linebr, linewidth=2, color=orange)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are plotting only when it is Sunday with `isSunday()` inside your `plot()`.

Instead, use a `var` to store the open price when it is Sunday, and update this variable the next Sunday.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Sunday Open", shorttitle="Sunday Open", overlay=true)
var float open_price = na
is_sunday = dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday
is_sunday_first_bar = not is_sunday[1] and is_sunday
open_price := is_sunday_first_bar ? open : open_price
plot(open_price, title="Sunday Open", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.orange)
```